# App Store - Installs by version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I recently released an update to my iOS app. Is there a way to tell in iTunesConnect how many users have updated to the new version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check in App Analytics section in iTunes-connect.
checked attached screenshot.[image]